# Trying to understand the Mellin transform of $\phi(x) \mathbf{1}_{\leq T}(x)$ where $\phi$ is smooth

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, mellin-transform

I am trying to understand the Mellin transform of $\phi(x) \mathbf{1}_{\leq T}(x)$ where $\phi$ is smooth and $\mathbf{1}_{\leq T}(x)$ is a function that is $1$ if $x\leq T$ and $0$ otherwise.

I would like to know two things: 1. Is it possible to get an expression in terms of $T$ and the Mellin transform of $\phi$? 2. If not, can we at least obtain a bound for it?

I have made an honest attempt trying to find the answer but I am quite lost at this and I would greatly appreciate any explanations/comments. Thank you very much.

Comment: Those kind of things are detailed in every course on the Fourier transform. See the [convolution theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem). Also why don't you explain what you really want to do ?

Comment: @reuns I appreciate your comments. I have tried looking at these things and I still don't get it... and that's why I thought I would give it a try here.